# How to deploy angular+mysql+springboot web app

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, deployment, web-applications

I developed a small web app with angular as front end using VS CODE, spring boot as back end using ECLIPSE IDE and mysql as database. I need to deploy it in a network of pc under proxy. I want the app run in a available computer (this machine always is turned on) inside the network and this app need to be always active and reachable by all the pc under that network.

I installed vs code, eclipse ide and everything in the machine to run the app as i usually do when i developed it so I tried to deploy it in the following way: in the terminal of vs code i run "ng serve --host [ip address of the machine]" and in Eclipse ide i run the spring boot app as normal. Everything works and i can reach the app running in the machine from all the pc inside the network typing in the search bar of the browsers the ip address and the port. However is there a better and more correct way to deploy this app? For example, if accidentally the machine turns off, i would like that, when it turns on, the app automatically starts without repeating the process of run command for terminal or run the app from IDE manually. How can i achieve this?

Comment: you'll want to use a web server.  But that all depends on what operating system the machine is on.  IIS for windows could work.  I definitely think you want to stay away from running the apps through the IDE to serve requests from everyone on the network.  That is a bad idea, and the apps will not be optimized unless you build artifacts and run them in production/release mode.

Comment: another option, if you are feeling brave, is using docker and docker-compose.  You could containerize your angular app, spring app, and database.  You could setup the network config so that these containers can talk to each other.

Comment: The operating system is windows. So i can use IIS to configure everything? Both angular and springboot and mysql? I'm completely new to this but i will learn about it. We have also windpws server in our network, should i use it?

Comment: you can start by running iis on your machine if you want, or use the windows server.  But you can register sites on iis, one for angular and one for springboot.  mysql will just run outside of iis and you just need to make sure it is installed on the machine you want to run everything on.